Can exist a positive integer number $x$ such that $a_1=x$ and $a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$ are not prime for all $n \ge 1$?

Using my computer, I found that the most of positive integer number $x$ such that $a_1=x$ and $a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$ is prime number after a few iterations. But exist some positive integer numbers, my computer can not checked this propety. For example, let $x=490$ then $a_1$, $a_2$, $\cdots$, $a_{60}$ are not prime number.

Can exist a positive integer number $x$ such that $a_1=x$ and $a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$ are not prime for all $n \ge 1$?



Note that $a_n = (x+1)*2^{n-1} - 1$.

In the OP example $x=490$, it is true that $a_n$ is not prime for $n\le 46$, however $a_{47} = 34551053391233023$ is prime, according to GP/PARI isprime function.

@ClaudeChaunier Thanks you very much. Maybe my program fail or not accuracy.

Per Dieter's comment, these are precisely $x$ such that $x+1$ is a Riesel number.

According to the link in Wojowu's comment it still seems open to determine the smallest Riesel number.

There are values of $x$ for which $a_n$ is never prime. Specifically, I will show that we can choose $x$ such that $a_n$ is always divisible by one of the primes $3$, $5$, $17$, $257$, $65537$, $641$ or $6700417$. These are the prime factors of $2^{64}-1$.
Note that, for $p$ one of these primes, the values of $2^j \bmod p$ repeat modulo $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$, $32$, $64$ and $64$ respectively. If we use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to choose $x$ appropriately modulo these primes, then we can arrange that
$$a_n \equiv 0 \bmod 
\begin{cases}
3 & \text{if}\ n \equiv 1 \bmod 2 \\
5 & \text{if}\ n \equiv 2 \bmod 4 \\
17 & \text{if}\ n \equiv 4 \bmod 8 \\
257 & \text{if}\ n \equiv 8 \bmod 16 \\
65537 & \text{if}\ n \equiv 16 \bmod 32 \\
641 &  \text{if}\ n \equiv 32 \bmod 64 \\
6700417 & \text{if}\ n \equiv 0 \bmod 64 \\
\end{cases}.$$
This covers all residue classes modulo $64$, so $a_n$ will never be prime.

Great insight. This yields $x = 5870726654493916467$.

I understand the proof, but I'm confused as to what “makes it work”. How difficult is it to find $n$ such that we can cover the residue classes mod $n$ by arithmetic sequences with difference $r_i$ where $r_i$ is the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $p_i$ where $p_i$ are the prime factors of $2^n-1$ (if I correctly summarized what property of $n=64$ is being used here)? Do you have additional insight to share? (Maybe this should be a separate question.)

My first heuristic was that I needed to find primes $p_i$ with $\text{ord}_2(p_i) = r_i$ and $\sum \tfrac{1}{r_i} >1$, since then residue classes modulo $r_i$ would be "enough" to cover. So I tried $p_i=3,5,7,13$, with $r_i = 2,4,3,6$. But I found that the resulting residue classes modulo $12$ overlapped too much. I saw that this would be better if, for each $r_i$ and $r_j$, either $r_i | r_j$ or vice versa. This suggested taking the $r_i$ to be powers of $2$, so that suggested factoring $2^{2^k}-1$. Then I remembered that $2^{32}+1$ isn't prime, so I tried $2^{64}-1$.

In general, given positive integers ${ r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k }$, I don't know when we should expect to be able to find residue classes $b_i$ such that the arithmetic progressions $b_i + r_i \mathbb{Z}$ cover $\mathbb{Z}$.

This argument goes back to the work of Erdős (https://renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1950-07.pdf) where he proved that if $m$ is an odd integer lying in a certain arithmetic progression, then $2^n+m$ is never prime. Also, a considerable research effort goes into studying covering systems of congruences, and this line of research was also initiated by Erdős. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system

@GHf, in that paper, Erdös proved there exists an arithmetic progression consisting
only of odd numbers, no term of which is of the form $2^n+p$. I believe that's different from the statement you give. Also, odd numbers not of the form $2^n+p$ are not hard to find – $127$ is such a number – they are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A006285. Erdös, as you say, deployed covering systems to show there are arithmetic progressions of such numbers. By contrast, there is no easy way to find any Riesel numbers (or Sierpinski numbers, related to $k\times2^n+1$) (continued)

(continued) without using covering systems to find an arithmetic progression of them, I think.

@GerryMyerson If you look into Erdős's paper, you will see that his argument really gives what I wrote in my previous comment above, and it uses covering systems of congruences. Note that the equation $2^n+p=-m$ is equivalent to $2^n+m=-p$. With the same method, you can prove Riesel's theorem. The method (covering systems of congruences) was introduced by Erdős in the 1930s (in connection with Romanov's theorem I believe). So David E Speyer rediscovered or remembered an old method of Erdős. I haven't seen Riesel's paper, but chances are that Riesel was guided by Erdős's earlier work.

@GHf, your statement is that there exists (an infinite arithmetic progression of odd) $m$ such that $2^n+m$ is never prime. Erdös proved there exists (an infinite etc.) $m$ such that $m-2^n$ is never prime. I don't see how a little algebra can show that these two statements are equivalent. As for the history, Romanov's paper is from 1934, Erdös' from 1950 (in connection, as you say, with Romanov's work from 1934). To the best of my knowledge, the 1950 paper was the first time Erdös, or anyone, used covering systems. I would like to see a citation of Erdös using covering systems in the 1930s.

@GerryMyerson Erdős proved that there exists an arithmetic progression $r+q\mathbb{Z}\subset 1+2\mathbb{Z}$ and a finite set $P$ of primes such that $\forall m\in r+q\mathbb{Z}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\exists p\in P:p\mid m-2^n$. Writing $\ell:=-m$, we get that $\forall \ell\in -r+q\mathbb{Z}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\exists p\in P:p\mid \ell+2^n$.

@GerryMyerson I agree that Erdős introduced covering systems in his 1950 paper. I was misled by the corresponding Wikipedia page quoted above which says "The notion of covering system was introduced by Paul Erdős in the early 1930s", and the fact that the problem solved by Erdős in 1950 was originally asked from him by Romanoff in 1934.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesel_number "a Riesel number is an odd natural number $k$ for which ${\displaystyle k\times 2^{n}-1}$ is composite for all natural numbers $n$."
"In 1956, Hans Riesel showed that there are an infinite number of integers $k$ such that ${\displaystyle k\times 2^{n}-1}$ is not prime for any integer $n$. He showed that the number $509203$ has this property, as does $509203$ plus any positive integer multiple of $11184810$."
Riesel numbers are generally found by producing covering sets, as in David Speyer's answer.
According to https://oeis.org/A040081/b040081.txt the smallest $n$ for which $491\times2^n-1$ is prime is $46$.

I can repeat my comment below David E Speyer's post. All this is essentially due to Erdős.
